# US Playstation Plus on EU Playstation on PS4

Tags: psn, ps4, playstation-plus

If I got an active US Playstation plus subscription on my alternative user. Would I be able to play games online on my main user(which is a EU account) that does not have an active ps+ subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PS+ has limited support for + features for other accounts on the console](http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5030).

> PlayStation Plus benefits available to other non-subscribing users on your Primary PS4:
>   Online multiplayer (subject to any parental control settings on sub accounts)
>   Play downloaded games purchased with PlayStation Plus discount
>   Play downloaded IGC games
>
> PlayStation Plus benefits not available to other users on your Primary PS4:
>   Purchasing PlayStation Plus discounted products from PlayStation Store
>   Online game save storage
>   Auto patch download
>   PlayStation Plus exclusive early access to game trial

So yes you can play PS+ games from the US account and play online, you'll miss out on several features like auto-cloud save backups, and you'll also have to log in with the US account with + to download free games (also EU/US PS+ games are occasionally different, especially on PS3). I'd strongly recommend getting PS+ on your *main* account rather than fussing with multiple accounts. The save data backup is nice, and the discounted games can make up for part (or all, if you buy a lot) of the subscription cost quite easily, as games are often an extra 25% or so off during sales with PS+.

Comment: I understand that this is not optimal, but since i already have a US PS+ code. I won`t bother paying for both regions the first year. Thanks.

Comment: @RoarG Alright, but do note that once the US PS+ ends you'll permanently lose access to the content claimed by it. If there's ~$50 worth of content you claim by the end of the year it might be best to just get EU PS+ (or alternately, just use the US account as the main one). It really pays to keep everything on one account due to the setup.